# "package javax.persistence does not exist" error in IntelliJ Community Edition

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

##### Problem :

I am trying to clone an already existing Spring Boot project on my local machine. This project runs hassle-free when loaded using **IntelliJ Idea Ultimate** but, when I try running it using **IntelliJ Community Edition** it throws an error :

```
Failed to read candidate component class: (1)\kipu-rcm-api\target\classes\com\kipu\ecal\entity\AbstractAuditingEntity.class]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceException
```

##### Steps Performed to reach this error :

- Deleted .m2 folder located at `C:\Users\{userName}\.m2`
- Extracted the content of the zip file.
- Loaded the project in IntelliJ (either Ultimate or Community edition) and ran the main class.
- Then it throws an error as follows -

  ```
   java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class QCommunicationGlobalSetting   location: package
  com.kipu.ecal.entity
  ```
- Then to fix error, `right clicked on project`->`maven`->`generate sources and update folder`
- Then again ran the application which runs successfully on Ultimate edition while same steps throw error on Community edition which says -

  ```
   Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Users\sprud\Downloads\kipu-rcm-api (1)\kipu-rcm-api\target\classes\com\kipu\ecal\entity\AbstractAuditingEntity.class]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceException
  ```

##### Here is my AbstractAuditingEntity class :

```
package com.kipu.ecal.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;


@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL, region = "entities")
@Setter
@Getter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private Boolean isDeleted = false;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Date createdDate;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_date")
    private Date updatedDate;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;
}
```

##### Here is my pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kipu</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecal</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ecal</name>
    <description>API Service of KIPU ECAL project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.20</lombok.version>
        <querydsl.version>5.0.0</querydsl.version>
        <networknt.version>1.0.68</networknt.version>
        <vladmihalcea.version>2.14.0</vladmihalcea.version>
        <ical.version>3.2.1</ical.version>
        <dependency-check-maven.version>6.5.3</dependency-check-maven.version>
        <postgres.version>42.3.8</postgres.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>9.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Fox swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>${vladmihalcea.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.networknt</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${networknt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgres.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- iText Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- iText pdfHTML add-on -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mnode.ical4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ical4j</artifactId>
            <version>${ical.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-search-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.dmfs/lib-recur -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dmfs</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-recur</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.pebbletemplates/pebble -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pebbletemplates</groupId>
            <artifactId>pebble</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.227</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-glue -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-glue</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.230</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-jwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        aws dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-fms</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.196</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.project-lombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

##### Some extra information

- java version installed on my machine - "17.0.6" 2023-01-17 LTS
- project jdk - Oracle OpenJDK version 19.0.2
- build tool - maven (default version used by IntelliJ)

**Note1 :** The same Project runs without any hassle on IntelliJ Idea Ultimate edition.
**Note2 :** I found a simple workaround to run this project even in Community edition which is that, if I try to comment this line `<scope> provided </scope>`   present within pom.xml file (as shown below), then it works fine :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE :** I have updated the pom.xml file, provided little more details from stack trace error, and also included the AbstractAuditingEntity class in the edited version of this SO post !!

Comment: Which version of intellij do you use?

Comment: Something else is wrong. Go back to the command line and make it work there first

Comment: @khmarbaise I work upon IntelliJ Community Edition 2022.3.2 as well as IntelliJ Ultimate Edition 2023.1.1

Comment: `Something else is wrong. Go back to the command line and make it work there first` - @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen can you guide me through how to make it work in terminal first ?

Comment: Just try an `mvn package` on plain command line... You have to install Maven, JDK correctly...

Comment: @khmarbaise firstly why do we even need to install maven cause I believe IntelliJ automatically provides us with maven ? Secondly if my JDK would have been installed wrongly then why would the project run smoothly on `IntelliJ Ultimate` but fails to run on `IntelliJ Community` edition, as ideally it should have failed and given error on both of the IDEs ?

Comment: **UPDATE :** I have updated the Post with couple more info regarding the error !!!

Comment: Because IntelliJ is another factor of possible issues... getting it ouf of the equation makes that equation easier to solve. Also Intellij automatically downloads the JDK and that is different from the way it works on plain command line...

Comment: Experienced programmers reduce to the smallest scenario possible, hence command line.  My guess is you have a broken project which confuses IntelliJ.

Comment: @khmarbaise I tried running in terminal using `mvn clean package` and I did get couple of errors which were related to - `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'aws.lambda' in value "${aws.lambda}"`

Comment: The thing is I had similar issues with their previous version of same backend project too but that project worked fine even on IntelliJ Community edition, so I believe there is some other issue. Also, I believe this is machine independent because I have a companion buddy who also tried running this project and gave similar behavior as mine  !!

Comment: The issues related to illegalArgumentException are a sign that your code/configuration is not ok...

Comment: @khmarbaise you must be right here but it still doesn't helps explaining the fact that I m able to run it in IntelliJ ultimate but not in the community edition. Also why does changing scope from provided to compile for following dependency : 
`<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>` fixes the issue even on Community edition ?

Comment: The first which comes into my mind is that you have defined spring-boot-starter-data-jpa but defining hibernate dependencies with a literal defined version which I would not recommend (except you know 100% what you are doing) furthermore the question is how you exactly starting your app in IntelliJ because there are some differences between community/ultimate edition related to Spring support which might be the reason for the issue .... https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=idea&product=idea-ce

Comment: @khmarbaise regarding the "`you've defined versions for the hibernate dependencies`", can you somehow point out what changes shall I make into the pom.xml [to rule out the first scenario given by you] ? Or at least gimme couple more hints so that I can head in right direction.

Comment: For example is this line one of the causes to fix in pom.xml file :  ```<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>```